# Python pyodbc: parse JSON list is wrong

Tags: python, sql, json, pyodbc

I'm parsing a JSON response from Yelp:

```
{
  "businesses": [
    {
      "id": "gaumont-wilson-toulouse-2",
      "name": "Gaumont Wilson",
      "city": "Toulouse"           
       }
    {
      "id": "la-cinémathèque-de-toulouse-toulouse",
      "name": "La Cinémathèque de Toulouse",
      "city": "Toulouse"
       }
    {
      "id": "abc-toulouse",
      "name": "ABC",
      "city": "Toulouse"
       }
  ]
}
```

and I write my Python code:

```
for element in response_data['businesses']:
    SQL_ID = element['id']
    SQL_Name = element['name']
    SQL_City = element['city']
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Yelp (ID, Name, City) values (?,?,?)", (SQL_ID,SQL_Name,SQL_City))
    connection.commit()
```

But as result Python just pass the last of the businesses and not the first two:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Your `response_data` is *not* valid JSON.

Comment: It's also not a valid Python dictionary. Therefore, I can't reprodruce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you load the json using `json.loads()`? If you didnt, try the following.

```
import json

reponse_data_json = json.loads(response_data)
for element in response_data_json['businesses']:
    SQL_ID = element['id']
    SQL_Name = element['name']
    SQL_City = element['city']
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Yelp (ID, Name, City) values (?,?,?)", (SQL_ID,SQL_Name,SQL_City))
    connection.commit()
```

Comment: as the others commented already, your json isn't valid. The dictionaries aren't comma seperated.

Answer (score 0):

your data is not a valid json format, i make a little change to add ',' after the each {}.then you could retrieve all as below, code tested under python 3.6

```
 data =  {
  "businesses": [
     {
       "id": "gaumont-wilson-toulouse-2",
       "name": "Gaumont Wilson",
       "city": "Toulouse"           
     },

     {
       "id": "la-cinémathèque-de-toulouse-toulouse",
       "name": "La Cinémathèque de Toulouse",
       "city": "Toulouse"
      },
    {
       "id": "abc-toulouse",
       "name": "ABC",
       "city": "Toulouse"
       },
  ]
}

 jsonobject = json.dumps(data)

 jsonobjectToString = json.loads(jsonobject)
 for resp in jsonobjectToString['businesses']:
     print(resp['id'])
     print(resp['name'])
     print(resp['city'])
```

=======

```
  gaumont-wilson-toulouse-2
  Gaumont Wilson
  Toulouse
  la-cinémathèque-de-toulouse-toulouse
  La Cinémathèque de Toulouse
  Toulouse
  abc-toulouse
  ABC
  Toulouse
```